# update function: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php, sql-update

I want to put update function. 
I already make a form, so after user will change everything he wants he can pus at "Save" and and this information will be updated. but when I push "Save", it doesn't save anything and shows error:

> "syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting
>   T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in V:\home\op\www\edit.php on
>   line 20"

And this is script, where information need to be updated. (I updated with your advices)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("university") or die(mysql_error()); 
$program = '".$_POST['program']."',
$code = '".$_POST['code']."',
$course = '".$_POST['course']."',
$form = '".$_POST['form']."',
$time = '".$_POST['time']."',
$price = '".$_POST['price']."',
$accreditation = '".$_POST['accreditation']."',
$department = '".$_POST['department']."',
$type = '".$_POST['level']."',
$type = '".$_POST['type']."',
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET program='".$_POST['program']."', code='".$_POST['code']."', course='".$_POST['course']."', form='".$_POST['form']."', time='".$_POST['time']."', price='".$_POST['price']."', accreditation='".$_POST['accreditation']."', department='".$_POST['department']."', level='".$_POST['level']."', type='".$_POST['type']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
if ($result == true) {
echo "Данные успешно сохранены!";
}
else {
echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку.";
}
```

Form(where user can put new information)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("university") or die(mysql_error());
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=" . intval($_GET['id']) );
if($res !== false)
{
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    $news=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    ?>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
        <label>Название <input name="program" type="text" id="program"     value="<?php echo $news['program'];?>" />
        <br />
        Код:  <input name="code" type="text" id="code"  value="<?php echo $news['price'];?>" />
        Курс:  <input name="course" type="text" id="course"  value="<?php echo $news['course'];?>" />
        Форма:  <input name="form" type="text" id="form"  value="<?php echo $news['form'];?>" />
        Срок:  <input name="time" type="text" id="time"  value="<?php echo $news['time'];?>" />
        Цена:  <input name="price" type="text" id="price"  value="<?php echo $news['price'];?>" />
        Акредитация:  <input name="accreditation" type="text" id="accreditation"  value="<?php echo $news['accreditation'];?>" />
        Кафедра:  <input name="department" type="text" id="department"  value="<?php echo $news['department'];?>" />
        Уровень:  <input name="level" type="text" id="level"  value="<?php echo $news['level'];?>" />
        Тип:  <input name="type" type="text" id="type"  value="<?php echo $news['type'];?>" />
        </label>
        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value=”<?php echo $news['id']?>”/>
        <input name="program" type="hidden" id="program" />
        <p>
        <label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="сохранить" />
        </label>
        </p>
        </div>
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo 'Нет новости с таким ID';
}
}
else
{
echo 'Ошибка запроса к DB';
}
```

Comment: just an advice , try not to use mysql* extensions as they are officially deprecated. Move your code to mysqli* or pdo* for better support,modularity,security.

Answer (score 2):

you need to correct your quoting for query variables and use `set` keyword try to change

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news program='$_POST['program']', code='$_POST['code']',    course='$_POST['course'], form='$_POST['form']', time='$_POST['time']',   price='$_POST['price']', accreditation='$_POST['accreditation']', department='$_POST['department']', level='$_POST['level']', type='$_POST['type']' WHERE id='$id'");
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news set program='".$_POST['program']."', code='".$_POST['code']."',    course='".$_POST['course']."', form='".$_POST['form']."', time='".$_POST['time']."',   price='".$_POST['price']."', accreditation='".$_POST['accreditation']."', department='".$_POST['department']."', level='".$_POST['level']."', type='".$_POST['type']."' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Also if you want to use your seted variables in query then use

```
mysql_query("UPDATE news set program='$program', code='$code',
```

...and so on

Also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent sql injection

**Note** :- stop using `mysql_*` functions use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: as mentioned by `Abhik` in his answer you need to add `set` to update query

Comment: i did as u said

`$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news program='".$_POST['program']."', code='".$_POST['code']."'`

but it didnt work, it showa my last message "echo "Произошла ошибка, пожалуйста повторите попытку." what means "Error, try again"

Comment: @user3624030 see `Abhik` answer. you need to add `SET` to update query

Comment: yes, i did it
`$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET program='".$_POST['program']."', code='".$_POST['code']."'`

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to check the update syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

The table update is done as

```
Update table set col = 'someval'
```

I dont see that `SET` in the query.

Then for all string values they must be enclosed with single quote

Further more you are wide open to sql injection and start using prepared statement with mysqli
or PDO

However in your case it should be as below until you learn preparedStatement

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news set 
program='".$_POST['program']."', 
code='".$_POST['code']."',  
course='".$_POST['course']."', 
form='".$_POST['form']."', 
time='".$_POST['time']."',   
price='".$_POST['price']."', 
accreditation='".$_POST['accreditation']."', 
department='".$_POST['department']."', 
level='".$_POST['level']."', 
type='".$_POST['type']."' 
WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: i added SET  and i changed 
`program='".$_POST['program']."', 
code='".$_POST['code']."',  `
but now it shows error
`syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in V:\home\op\www\edit.php on line 10` 
it means here: `$program = '".$_POST['program']."',`

Comment: can update the question with the new code that you have since I dont see any syntax error.

Comment: Oh no you are doing it wrong, I have added the complete update code https://eval.in/151621 check how it should look like.

Comment: pff i dont know whats wrong with me, now it says 
`Undefined variable: id in V:\home\op\www\edit.php on line 16`
but i think its ok, right? Just very strange that now it shows my message "echo "Данные успешно сохранены!" what means that "information was successfully saved" but when i check the database i dont see any changes

Comment: I know you need to add this line `$id = $_POST['id']` before the query and it should fix it.

Comment: it didnt help
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in V:\home\op\www\edit.php on line 16`  its about `WHERE $id = $_POST['id']");`

Comment: i added this code that u gave me, but it says 
`unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in V:\home\op\www\edit.php on line 16`
 its about `WHERE $id = $_POST['id']");`

Comment: are you using the code from https://eval.in/151636 ? this a new one I added there is no `$id = $_POST['id']`

Comment: yes, i used it
and it show message my message "Error, try again"
Im sorry, i think u already get sick from this) all the time my mistakes

Comment: echo the query and try executing it directly on mysql or phpmyadmin if there is any error it will show you that.